# Mapbox API KEY for Flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I am learning mapbox using the flutter plugin, but i got struck when i try to use this plugin. I don't know where i can get mapbox search api_key.
I tried searching in the application [website](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_search), but there isn't enough information. Where i can get the api_key.

```
MapBoxPlaceSearchWidget(
      popOnSelect: true,
      apiKey:
          "API KEY",
      limit: 10,
      onSelected: (place) {},
      context: context,
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google is your friend, search for `mapbox api key` and you'll find results like this: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/access-tokens/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a Mapbox account and API access token. 
You can use https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens/ 
After create account , you can create access token

[image]

[image]

Comment: is API_key and Access token similar?

Comment: the same one. I have made example code work. you can see my updated answer.